# early stopping in lstm with Python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm

How to do early stopping in lstm.

I am using python tensorflow but not keras.

I would appreciate if you can provide a sample python  code.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You can do it Using `checkpoints`:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
earlyStop=EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",verbose=2,mode='min',patience=3)
history=model.fit(xTrain,yTrain,epochs=100,batch_size=10,validation_data=(xTest,yTest) ,verbose=2,callbacks=[earlyStop])
```

Training will stop when "val_loss" has not decreased(`mode='min'`)  even after 3 epochs(`patience=3`)

```
#Didn't realize u were note using keras
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find it with a little search 
https://github.com/mmuratarat/handson-ml/blob/master/11_deep_learning.ipynb

```
max_checks_without_progress = 20
checks_without_progress = 0
best_loss = np.infty

....

    if loss_val < best_loss:
        save_path = saver.save(sess, './my_mnist_model.ckpt')
        best_loss = loss_val
        check_without_progress = 0
    else:
        check_without_progress +=1
        if check_without_progress > max_checks_without_progress:
            print("Early stopping!")
            break

    print("Epoch: {:d} - ".format(epoch), \
          "Training Loss: {:.5f}, ".format(loss_train), \
          "Training Accuracy: {:.2f}%, ".format(accuracy_train*100), \
          "Validation Loss: {:.4f}, ".format(loss_val), \
          "Best Loss: {:.4f}, ".format(best_loss), \
          "Validation Accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(accuracy_val*100))
```